# Similar matrices over different fields

Tags: linear-algebra

I would love your help with this:

Let $F$ be a field and $F\subset K$ a field extension.

Let $A,B\in M_{5}(F)$.

How does one prove that if $A$ and $B$ are similar in $F$, then they are similar in $K$?

Thank you.

Comment: Write out what it means for A,B to be similar as matrices over F.

Comment: The converse is not quite as trivial. For that you can use the fact that if a system of linear equations over $F$ has a solution over $K$, then it has a solution over $F$.

Comment: This direction is almost trivial. The reverse direction is much more interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $L$ be a field. We say that two matrices $X,Y\in M_n(L)$ are [similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similar_matrix) when there is an invertible $P\in M_n(L)$ such that
$$Y=P^{-1}XP.$$
Because $F\subset K$, we can choose to view a matrix with entries in $F$ as also being a matrix with entries in $K$.

Thus, if $A$ and $B$ are similar as matrices in $F$, that is, if 
$$B=P^{-1}AP$$
where $P\in M_5(F)$ is an invertible matrix, then we also have that $A$ and $B$ are similar as matrices in $K$, that is, 
$$B=Q^{-1}AQ$$
where $Q\in M_5(K)$ is an invertible matrix - namely, we just take $Q=P$, viewed as a matrix with entries in $K$.