# $A$ is similar to $B$ in $E$ if only if $A$ is similar to $B$ in $F$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

If $E$ is a field, $F/E$ is a field extension, let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices with entries in $E$ then $A$ is similar to $B$ in $E$ if only if $A$ is similar to $B$ in $F$. I think it's true, but I don't know how to prove it. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35937/similar-matrices-over-different-fields